# Chrome blocks download of tar file, giving a resume button and "Check internet connection" - recent problem, is there a solution?

Tags: google-chrome, download

Users of my app, which has been released for a couple of years, are suddenly reporting that when they click a link in the app to download a database backup tar file they are getting the download failing. The downloads tab shows a resume button (which doesn't work) and the error message "Check internet connection". The connection is fine.

At the moment it appears that a workaround is to do a hard reload, which allows you to download one file, then you have to hard reload again to do a second file.

Is there something I can tell users to reconfigure in the browser to avoid this problem and not have to reload every time they need a download?